# How to know the item details from the box details and total quantity of items in it

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, packing-problem

Currently I am trying to solve a problem in which I am having total size of the box(L,B,H) in which I have to fill a particular quantity of items of same size. I have the knowledge of total quantity of items that can be filled in the box. Can we guess the actual size(L,B,H) of each item in the box.

Given facts - size of the box, total quantity of item that can be filled in the box completely.
To calculate - size(L,B,H) of that item that has been filled.

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct answer here.

If the items are rectangular prisms or cubes of the appropriate size, then the box will be totally filled with little or no remaining space. Thus each item is approximately (volume of box)/(number of items) in size.

If the items are spheres, then there is some space left over, and the same estimate will give an overestimate for the volume of each item.

And if items are more irregular in shape, then the estimate can be much worse.

Comment: In my problem I am looking for only items that are filled completely inside a box(not spheres). We can caluclate the volume of each item as you said by dividing the total volume by number of items. But I am keen to know is there any way by which we can know the length.width and depth of the items from the box dimensions. Thanks